# Some doubts related to the use of CSS clear property in a specifi case

Tags: html, css

maybe this is a stupid question but I have a doubt about CSS **clear** propery use.

I have this template: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

Why if I delete (you can try with firebug) the propery **clear: both** from the **#footcontainer** div I obtain that this div is placed at the top (it seems almost below the header and below the two columns)

My idea is this thing happens because the two columns #content and #sidebar are floated to the left and without setting **clear: both** on the **#footcontainer** div the browser try to put also this div on the right of the *#content** div but have no space and put at the top.

Is this a right intuition or am I missing something?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: You should not require your css file via import, but straight from the tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because everytime you float an element, its container loses its auto height. 
 If you want to prevent that from happening, there are somethings you can do:

**Set a given height to the container**

Ex:

```
<div class="my-container" style="height: 100px">
  <div style="float: left;">
    Some very interesting text right here.
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    Don't read this and you'll be doomed.
  </div>
</div>
```

Be aware that if you have set a given height, the div won't resize as the content becomes higher than the container.

**Append a div with `style="clear: both"` right after the floated elements**

Ex:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div style="float: left;">
      Some very interesting text right here.
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
      Don't read this and you'll be doomed.
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
```

Yeah, it works. But only noobs do it like that. It's not elegant and pollutes your code.

**Set `overflow: hidden` to the parent container**

```
<div class="my-container" style="overflow: hidden">
    <div style="float: left;">
      Some very interesting text right here.
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
      Don't read this and  you'll be doomed.
    </div>
  </div>
```

This one is great, but you are in danger if you have someting positioned absolutely and have to move it outside the parent div, for example. You'll have an unpleasant surprise.

**Use the ClearFix Hack.**

This is the way I do it: easy to implement and works like a charm. Check this link out: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html;

If you  mind about not having valid CSS (like me), you can target IE browsers with a different stylesheet and conditional comments, for example.

Further resources about the subject:

- Quirks Mode Site: CSS Clearing
  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
- Chris Coyier's ClearFix Tutorial
  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

**I see you code**

your code is too **complicated according to me** but any way **you can used** to `this css` than **your problem is solve**

**Used to this css**

```
#c{position:relative;}
        #c:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: -42px;
        background: url('http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/images/footerRight.jpg') no-repeat -3px 0px;
        height: 43px;
        }
    #footerRight{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no height set on your container. If you change the height of container to the height of its' contents, which in this case is 596 px then when you take away the clear both property on the footer it won't move one iota.

Comment: Please can you explain me better this thing (I am very interested to it). Yoy say me that the height of the content is 596px, how do you see it? I have no set height to the #content div. What you mean exactly? Can you explain me in details?
Tnx

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because if you float an object, the parent object doesn't resize accordingly.

For example, if you had:

```
<div class="1px-border">
    <div class="float">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The border would be completely flat, and not resize to the header. You could fix it by having overflow: auto in the container div.

That said, I could be massively wrong.